# Sort an large array, keeping some elements in place (every language)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic, array-algorithms

Can everybody help me? I have a problem: Given an array of array elements (Unlimited number of array elements). Sort the elements in ascending order, but keep any elements with the value -1 in the original position.

example: `a=[4, -1, 5, 1, 8, 3, 2, -1]`

after sort: `a=[1, -1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, -1]`

Comment: ex:a=[4, -1, 5, 1, 8, 3, 2, -1]

 after sort: a=[1, -1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, -1]

Comment: There are hundreds (or thousands) of programming languages. Do you want someone to give you an example for every one?

Comment: I think OP wrote "every" where he meant "any".  This is actually an interesting question.

Comment: That mean is Choose a language you use. Can you help me ?

Comment: You could use merge sort, with the compare modified so if either element is -1, then return what is needed to indicate the elements are in place. For example, if using C++ std::stable_sort, the order of parameters is reversed to work with a compare for less than: compare(right element, left element), and if either element is -1, return 0, which would indicate "in place" for std::stable_sort().

Comment: If the number of array elements is large and element "-1" is many , how to optimize it?It stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you might accomplish that in C#:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NameSpace
{
    class Class
    {
        static int[] a = { 4, -1, 5, 1, 8, 3, 2, -1 };
        static List<int> Storage = new List<int>();
        static int indexToAdd = 0;
        static void Main()
        {
            foreach(int i in a)
            {
                if(i != -1)
                {
                    Storage.Add(i);
                }
            }
            Storage.Sort();

            for(int i = 0; i < Storage.Count; i++)
            {
                if(a[indexToAdd + i] == -1)
                {
                    indexToAdd++;
                }
                a[indexToAdd + i] = Storage[i];
            }

            foreach(int i in a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new list with the indices of every item that is not -1, i.e. the indices of the items that need sorting, then follow one of the examples in this RosettaCode Task: [Sort disjoint sublist](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sort_disjoint_sublist)